# Is that possible to solve the following differential equation by using laplace transform?

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

Is that possible to solve the following differential equation by using laplace transform?

$$y''-t^2y'+y=e^{2t};\quad y(0)=1,\quad y'(0)=1$$

??

I knew that if there is coefficient except $1$ with the variable $y$ , then laplace transform can't be derived.

Comment: No, the DEQ does not have a closed form, but it is also not possible to use the LT.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB gives the solution in terms of [Heun Triconfluent function](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=HeunT).